# Nullable<T>: and overloaded operators, bool? & bool

Tags: c#, nullable

1. Why is operator '&' defined for bool?, and operator '&&' is not?
2. How exactly does this 1) bool? & bool? and 2) bool? and bool work?

Any other "interesting" operator semantics on Nullable? Any overloaded operators for generic T?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Operators on `Nullable<T>` are "lifted" operators. What this means is: if T has the operator, T? will have the "lifted" counterpart.

&& and || aren't really operators in the same sense as & and | - for example, they can't be overloaded - from the ECMA spec 14.2.2 Operator overloading:

> The overloadable binary operators are:
>   + - * / % & | ^ << >> == != > < >= <= Only the operators listed above can be
>   overloaded. In particular, it is not
>   possible to overload member access,
>   method invocation, or the =, &&, ||,
>   ??, ?:, checked, unchecked, new,
>   typeof, as, and is operators.

Likewise, from the ECMA spec, 14.2.7 Lifted operators, the lifted operators are:

> For the unary operators
>   + ++ - -- ! ~
>
> For the binary operators
>   + - * / % & | ^ << >>
>
> For the equality operators
>   == !=
>
> For the relational operators < > <= >=

So basically, the short-circuiting operators aren't defined as lifted operators.

[edit: added crib sheet]

- Lifted operator: a compiler provided operator on `Nullable<T>`, based on the operators of T - for example: the `int` "+" operator gets "lifted" onto `int?`, defined as:

  (int? x, int? y) => (x.HasValue && y.HasValue) ? (x.Value + y.Value) : (int?) null;
- Operator overloading: the act of providing a custom operator implementation for a given type; for example `decimal` and `DateTime` provide various operator overloads
- Short-circuiting: the normal behavior of `&&` and `||` (in many languages, including C++ and C#) - i.e. the second operand *might not be evaluated* - i.e.

  (expression1, expression2) => expression1() ? expression2() : false;

Or perhaps a simpler example:

```
bool someFlag = Method1() && Method2();
```

if `Method1()` returns false, then `Method2()` isn't executed (since the compiler already knows that the overall answer is false). This is important if `Method2()` has side-effects, since as saving to the database...

Comment: Thanks. However, after C++, all this terminology...short-circuit, lifted...impossibility to override &&...sounds quite strange to me :)

Answer (score 4):

There are no short-circuiting operators (&& ||)  defined for `bool?`

Only are the logical AND, inclusive OR, operators and they behave like this:

```
x        y      x & y   x | y   
true    true    true    true
true    false   false   true
true    null    null    true
false   true    false   true
false   false   false   false
false   null    false   null
null    true    null    true
null    false   false   null
null    null    null    null
```

Comment: Thanks. Maybe can also explain why they are called short-circuiting, these && and || ?

Comment: They are "short-circuiting" because they only evaluate multiple conditions in a logical statement if necessary. See http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators for more information.

Comment: @ScottDorman  To be clear for other readers, in C# the operators | or & are NOT short-circuiting for bool?, even in the latest C# 10.   (Your comment did not tag the previous commenter, and it wasn't immediately clear you were responding to the comment rather than the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Operator "&" is bitwise operator, ¨whereas "&&" is logical operator.
The logcial "AND" operator can not be aplied to the threestate value, only for twostate.

Answer (score 0):

-- In addition, the logical && operator along with the || operator cannot be overloaded.

2) The reason that the bitwise operator works is because it operates on single bits, which is a simple 1 or 0.  This is what boolean operators essentially are, true and false, 1 and 0.