# Why are there no lifted short-circuiting operators on `bool?`?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, short-circuiting, lifted-operators

Why doesn't `bool?` support lifted `&&` and `||`? They could have lifted the `true` and `false` operators which would have indirectly added lifted `&&` and `||`.

The operators `|` and `&` are already lifted and implement the correct [Three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic). But of course they are not short circuiting like `||` and `&&`.

The question is why they decided not to lift those operators when creating the specification. So "It's like this because the spec says so" is no answer to the "why?".

When lifting `true` and `false` so that `null` is neither `true` nor `false`:

```
public static bool operator true(bool? x) 
{
    return x.HasValue && x.Value
}

public static bool operator false(bool? x) 
{
  return x.HasValue && !x.Value
}
```

This would have resulted in `&&` and `||` behaving just like their non short-circuiting counterparts. Except that `false && anything` and `true || anything` would short circuit (`false` and `true` are no compile time constants in these two examples).

This would work very similar to the [DBBool example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx).

I see no surprising or dangerous behavior introduced by lifting these operators. Did I miss something?

I have read [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303181/nullablet-and-overloaded-operators-bool-bool) on this, but found none of the answers satisfying.

---

Jeff Yates's answer shows a nice reason for why lifting the `true`/`false` operators isn't optimal, it doesn't explain why lifting `&&` and `||` directly is bad. Since operator lifting is compiler magic that special cases `Nullable<T>` it doesn't need to follow the overloading rules for normal types and thus would be able to offer `&&`/`||` without lifting `true`.

Comment: Wouldn't this assume that NULL means false ? Not everyone would agree with that. In e.g. relational theory (and SQL) `NULL AND true , NULL and NULL, FALSE OR NULL` is .. NULL, which is neither true nor false

Comment: The operator `false` applied to `null` returns false. This leads to `&&` not short circuiting and returning `null&anything` instead.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic

Comment: I am sure that there will be a lot of meaningless answers. only Eric Lipper can give meaningful one, let's hope that he catches the question :)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing your point but, if x is null in your code above, then `true(x) == false(x);`. That would hardly seem to make any sense.

Comment: @nos for example `WHERE` clause in SQL treats `NULL` as result of conditional expression as `false`, example `WHERE X = NULL` return empty set, because it is always false, even for NULL. so this is just a projection of three-state logic to two-state logic.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood take a look it's implementation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6292hy1k.aspx when it is 0 then `true(x) == false(x)`

Comment: @Jonathan Wood which result would you expect for value that is neither `true` nor `false`? it will return `false` for both.

Comment: @Jonathan I don't think that this is a problem by itself. Three values logic is a bit strange.

Comment: I want to mention in C# you can write `v = null | true;` and it will compile. Its returns true, however `v = null | false` is null instead of false because you cant say it is false since null is not false. An easy way to thin of it is what CodeInChaos said to me, pretend null is (false&&true) and do the operations ;). I believe the question is, if null & boolval is legal why does null && boolval not compile. He doesnt see any harmful effects

Comment: @acid I didn't say null is `false&&true` but that it can assume both values. Probably just a misleading formulation on your part.

Comment: @Andrey While Eric Lippert can give the definitive answer on why they did it like this, other people can give reasons for why it is a good or bad idea. The doubt the C# team did decide this one a whim. I'm sure they had reasons why they consider it a bad idea. And these reasons can be discovered by other people too.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I see. Well, anways, it worked. It made me remember and correctly as well!

Comment: @CodeInChaos personally I didn't even understand your question :) concept of lifted operators passed me by.

Comment: @Andrey The idea of lifted operators is that a nullable offers the same operators as it's underlying type, and adds sensible behavior for the case for null values. They lifted most operators including `&` and `|` but not `&&` and `||`.

Comment: @CodeInChaos i guess it is because they (`&&` and `||`) can't be overloaded, and this rule was there before nullables. They decided to play their own rules :)

Comment: You can indirectly overload `&&` and `||` on your own types by overloading `true` and `false`. The `DBBool` type in the example I posted does exactly that. And of course all lifted operators are compiler magic and not possible by simply adding operators to `Nullable<T>`. In particular they are only available if the underlying type has them, and they mimic the types the corresponding operators on the underlying type use(made nullable of course).

Answer (score 4):

What you propose would create two different usage patterns for nullable types.

Consider the following code:

```
bool? a = null;

// This doesn't currently compile but would with lifted true/false operators.
if (a)
{
}

// Whereas this provides a consistent use of nullable types.
if (a ?? false)
{
}
```

For consistency in the usage of nullable types, it makes sense to not lift the `true` and `false` operators on `bool`. I don't know if this is the real reason why it wasn't done, but it makes sense to me.

Comment: I didn't know that `if` uses the `true` operator. I thought it requires an implicit conversion to `bool`. But I just tested it and you're right. Still this doesn't explain why they wouldn't lift && and || directly without lifting `true` or `false`.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: How could you? && and || require booleans on either side (see spec) - without lifting `true` or `false`, it can't be done.

Answer (score 4):

Since you showed that lifting `true` and `false` is technically possible, there are only two possible answers to your question (with "they" being the people who wrote the compiler/spec):

1. It's an error in the spec, ie. they didn't think of this. (possible, but I doubt that)
2. They thought that lifting the short-circuiting operators is potentially error-prone. It could be the same way of reasoning as why C# is completely class based (no sole functions as in C++) or why a statement like `if (myNullVar) { ... }` (with `myNullVar` being a reference) doesn't work in C# (but it does in C/C++).

I think there's always a balance between making a programming language more powerful and making it less error-prone.

**Update:** Just for you interest, that's what the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384091.aspx) says:

> This is not allowed because it is unclear what null means in the context of a conditional.

Comment: This answer shows very nicely why lifting `op_true`/`op_false` is a bad idea given the way conditionals are implemented(IMO using `op_true` in conditionals is stupid, I'd require implicit convertibility to bool) it does not show why the short circuited operators shouldn't be lifted directly.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: When C# made the (IMHO) unfortunate decision to implicitly hoist all operators on nullable types using the formulation that the result should be `null` if either operand was `null`, that meant that `true | null` and `false & null` can not evaluate to `true` and `false`, respectively, as would be the case with three-value logic, but instead must evaluate to `null` for consistency with other hoisted operators.  The normal meaning of `&&` and `||` is that they should return the same value as `&` and `|` would if given the same operands, but only evaluate the right operand...

Comment: ...when its value could affect the result.  While it would be possible to have `&&` and `||` in such fashion as to be consistent with `&` and `|` by evaluating the right-hand side when the left-hand operand is non-null, it would be rather surprising if, given `bool b=false; bool? bq = false;`, the expression `bq && f()` evaluated the right-hand side even though `b & f()` would not.

Comment: @supercat But the C# specification has a particular section on operators of form `bool? operator |(bool? x, bool? y)` and `bool? operator &(bool? x, bool? y)`, and it clearly makes an exception for `bool?`, to the rule that if any operand does not `HasValue`, the result will be `null` as well. So `true | null` ***is*** `true`. See for yourself. However, the spec is quite unclear when it comes to `||` and `&&` and nullables. I recently [asked a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508991/) about that.

Answer (score 0):

`false && anything` is the same as `false`. However if you expect `false && anything` to be true only if `anything` is false, then `!anything` is what you want.

Also, `true || anything` is the same as `true`. ...And I'm not sure how you could have it return false on any condition, as it would make no sense to have "this or that" return nothing!

... why adding additional weight to the condition when it's all clear and simple as it is?

I am not usually an adept of "because this is so", but I fail to see the advantage of adding such functionality.

Comment: I don't mean `false` being a compile-time constant in that example. But an expression that already has evaluated to false, and thus making the evaluation of the right side unnecessary.

Comment: false && anything is false. no?

Comment: oh! so, you are talking about `cond1 && cond2` while you want `cond2` be be evaluated even if `cond1` is false?