# Lambda expression with <bool> and System.Nullable<bool>

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda, expression, nullable

This can't compile:

```
void Foo()
{
    using (var db = new BarDataContext(ConnectionString))
    {
        // baz is type 'bool'
        // bazNullable is type 'System.Nullable<bool>'
        var list = db.Bars.Where(p => p.baz && p.bazNullable); // Compiler: 
            // Cannot apply operator '&&' to operands of type
            // 'System.Nullable<bool> and 'bool'
    }
}
```

Do I really have to make this through two runs, where I first use the  as condition and then run through that list with the nullable conditions, or is there a better clean smooth best practice way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
p.bazNullable.GetValueOrDefault()
```

Comment: +1 for this one. nice. i didn't know there is a `GetValueOrDefault`.

Comment: I couldn't use `GetValueOrDefault` in a LINQ query, but explicitly adding `== true` worked.

Comment: You can pass a default value as well like this in GetValueOrDefault(false).
It will return false if the bool contains null value. Helped me tremendously in LINQ where clauses.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
 db.Bars.Where(p => p.baz && p.bazNullable.HasValue && p.bazNullable.Value);
```

I don't know if Linq-to-Sql can handle it.

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues here:

The shortcircuiting `&&` is not supported on nullable types for some reason. (Related [Why are there no lifted short-circuiting operators on `bool?`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204366/why-are-there-no-lifted-short-circuiting-operators-on-bool))

The second is that even if it were supported by C#, your code still makes no sense. `Where` needs a `bool` as result type of your condition, not a `bool?`. So you need to decide how the case where `baz==true` and `bazNullable==null` should be treated.

This leads to either `p.baz && (p.bazNullable==true)` or `p.baz && (p.bazNullable!=false)` depending on what you want.

Or alternatively `p.baz && (p.bazNullable??false)` or `p.baz && (p.bazNullable??true)`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to apply a logical && operation to a nullable bool.

If you are sure that p.bazNullable is not null, then you can try

```
var list = db.Bars.Where(p => p.baz && p.bazNullable.Value);
```

or if a null value equates to false, then try

```
var list = db.Bars.Where(p => p.baz && p.bazNullable.ValueOrDefault(false));
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
  var list = db.Bars.Where(p => p.baz && p.bazNullable.Value);
```

To handle null exceptions use:

```
  var list = db.Bars.Where(p => p.baz && p.bazNullable != null && p.bazNullable.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just do:

```
var list = db.Bars.Where(p => p.baz && p.bazNullable != null && p.bazNullable == true);
```

Comment: Checking `HasValue` is a lot simpler, but that could also work.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
Where(p => p.baz && (p.bazNullable ?? false));
```

OR

```
Where(p => p.baz && (p.bazNullable ==null ? false : p.bazNullable.Value));
```

Comment: Might it be safer to use nullable HasValue instead of checking for just nulls? Example:
Where(p => p.baz && (p.bazNullable.HasValue && p.bazNullable.Value));