# Looking for explanation of a boolean statement

Tags: c#, boolean

I found this statement in a library I am using. It is supposed to check if the current node in the cluster is a leader. This is the statement: `(!(cluster.Leader?.IsRemote ?? true))`

Why not just use `(cluster.Leader?.IsRemote)`? (disregard the ! operator, I know how that works)

Are there any benefits to this approach?

Comment: Cause using former one will end up being  `bool` and latter - `bool?`. And it depends on context what is more appropriate (also obviously you will have different values in case of `Leader` being `null`). Also latter one can't be directly used in statements requiring `bool` like `if`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's build a *truth table* for

```
 (!(cluster.Leader?.IsRemote ?? true))
```

construction (note that we have *three* values to consider: `true`, `false`, `null`):

```
 (!(cluster.Leader?.IsRemote ?? true)) : Result 
 ----------------------------------------------
                                  true : false
                                 false :  true <- the only true we have
                                  null : false
```

So, if you are looking for a *simplification* you can put it as

```
 (cluster.Leader?.IsRemote == false)
```

Answer (score 5):

It means that if `cluster.Leader?.IsRemote` is `null` then consider is as true `?? true`

Effectively `null ?? true` equals `true`.

So if your `leader` is null, then the whole statement will return false). Without the `?? null` your statement would not even compile, as `!null` means nothing.

Comment: Why did you remove the accept from this answer? What is missing?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following code:

```
public class Foo
{
    public bool IsBar { get; set; }
}

var foo = new Foo();

Console.WriteLine(!(foo?.IsBar ?? true));
```

While `IsBar` is declared as a regular, non-nullable bool, the `?` operator in `foo?.IsBar` makes that expression of type `bool?`, not `bool`.

You can't use nullable bools in boolean expressions, see also [if condition with nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911696/if-condition-with-nullable), so you need to make the expression explicit: what should happen if `foo`, and therefore `foo?.IsBar` is `null`?

That's where `?? true` comes in. Alternatives:

```
Console.WriteLine(!(foo?.IsBar).GetValueOrDefault(true));
Console.WriteLine(foo?.IsBar == false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the following code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Cluster cluster = new Cluster { Leader = null };
        var libresult = (!(cluster.Leader?.IsRemote ?? true));
        var result = (!(cluster.Leader?.IsRemote));
    }

}

class Cluster
{
   public Leader Leader { get; set; }
}

class Leader
{
    public bool IsRemote { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see *Leader is null* in above code

if consider condition as

```
var result = (!(cluster.Leader?.IsRemote));
```

then

> Null-conditional/Elvis operator(?.)

return null for `cluster.Leader?.IsRemote` so, !(null) will be ***null***.

but if consider condition as

```
var libresult = (!(cluster.Leader?.IsRemote ?? true));
```

then as we have see above Null-conditional/Elvis operator(?.) return null for `cluster.Leader?.IsRemote`
so, now condition is  `!(null ?? true)`

According to

> Null-collation(??) operator

`(null ?? true)` will return *true*. and !(true) will be ***false***

> so, benefit of "**?? true**" is that if left hand side value is null
> then it should be consider as Boolean(true).