# Do short-circuiting operators || and && exist for nullable booleans? The RuntimeBinder sometimes thinks so

Tags: c#, nullable, logical-operators, short-circuiting, dynamictype

I read the C# Language Specification on the *Conditional logical operators* `||` and `&&`, also known as the short-circuiting logical operators. To me it seemed unclear if these existed for nullable booleans, i.e. the operand type `Nullable<bool>` (also written `bool?`), so I tried it with non-dynamic typing:

```
bool a = true;
bool? b = null;
bool? xxxx = b || a;  // compile-time error, || can't be applied to these types
```

That seemed to settle the question (I could not understand the specification clearly, but assuming the implementation of the Visual C# compiler was correct, now I knew).

However, I wanted to try with `dynamic` binding as well. So I tried this instead:

```
static class Program
{
  static dynamic A
  {
    get
    {
      Console.WriteLine("'A' evaluated");
      return true;
    }
  }
  static dynamic B
  {
    get
    {
      Console.WriteLine("'B' evaluated");
      return null;
    }
  }

  static void Main()
  {
    dynamic x = A | B;
    Console.WriteLine((object)x);
    dynamic y = A & B;
    Console.WriteLine((object)y);

    dynamic xx = A || B;
    Console.WriteLine((object)xx);
    dynamic yy = A && B;
    Console.WriteLine((object)yy);
  }
}
```

The surprising result is that this runs without exception.

Well, `x` and `y` are not surprising, their declarations lead to both properties being retrieved, and the resulting values are as expected, `x` is `true` and `y` is `null`.

But the evaluation for `xx` of `A || B` lead to no binding-time exception, and only the property `A` was read, not `B`. Why does this happen? As you can tell, we could change the `B` getter to return a crazy object, like `"Hello world"`, and `xx` would still evaluate to `true` without binding-problems...

Evaluating `A && B` (for `yy`) also leads to no binding-time error. And here both properties are retrieved, of course. Why is this allowed by the run-time binder? If the returned object from `B` is changed to a "bad" object (like a `string`), a binding exception does occur.

***Is this correct behavior?*** (How can you infer that from the spec?)

If you try `B` as first operand, both `B || A` and `B && A` give runtime binder exception (`B | A` and `B & A` work fine as everything is normal with non-short-circuiting operators `|` and `&`).

(Tried with C# compiler of Visual Studio 2013, and runtime version .NET 4.5.2.)

Comment: There are no instances of `Nullable<Boolean>` involved at all, only boxed booleans treated as `dynamic` -- your test with `bool?` is irrelevant. (Of course, this is not a full answer, only the germ of one.)

Comment: Have you experimented with `x.HasValue && x.Value || y.HasValue && y.Value`? You need to be explicit, one way or another, about how you want nulls handled.

Comment: The `A || B` makes a certain amount of sense, in that you don't want to evaluate `B` unless `A` is false, which it's not. So you never know the type of the expression, really. The `A && B` version is more surprising - I'll see what I can find in the spec.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Well, unless the compiler were to decide that if the type of `A` is `bool` and the value of `B` is `null`, then a `bool && bool?` operator might be involved.

Comment: Interestingly, it looks like this has exposed a compiler or spec bug. The C# 5.0 specification for `&&` talks about resolving it as if it were `&` instead, and specifically includes the case where both operands are `bool?` - but then the next section it refers to doesn't handle the nullable case. I could add a sort of answer going into more detail on that, but it wouldn't fully explain it.

Comment: I've emailed Mads about the spec problem, to see whether it's just an issue in how I'm reading it...

Answer (score 67, accepted):

First of all, thanks for pointing out that the spec isn't clear on the non-dynamic nullable-bool case. I will fix that in a future version. The compiler's behavior is the intended behavior; `&&` and `||` are not supposed to work on nullable bools.

The dynamic binder does not seem to implement this restriction, though. Instead, it binds the component operations separately: the `&`/`|` and the `?:`. Thus it's able to muddle through if the first operand happens to be `true` or `false` (which are boolean values and thus allowed as the first operand of `?:`), but if you give `null` as the first operand (e.g. if you try `B && A` in the example above), you do get a runtime binding exception.

If you think about it, you can see why we implemented dynamic `&&` and `||` this way instead of as one big dynamic operation: dynamic operations are bound at runtime *after their operands are evaluated*, so that the binding can be based on the runtime types of the results of those evaluations. But such eager evaluation defeats the purpose of short-circuiting operators! So instead, the generated code for dynamic `&&` and `||` breaks the evaluation up into pieces and will proceed as follows:

- Evaluate the left operand (let's call the result `x`)
- Try to turn it into a `bool` via implicit conversion, or the `true` or `false` operators (fail if unable)
- Use `x` as the condition in a `?:` operation
- In the true branch, use `x` as a result
- In the false branch, *now* evaluate the second operand (let's call the result `y`)
- Try to bind the `&` or `|` operator based on the runtime type of `x` and `y` (fail if unable)
- Apply the selected operator

This is the behavior that lets through certain "illegal" combinations of operands: the `?:` operator successfully treats the first operand as a *non-nullable* boolean, the `&` or `|` operator successfully treats it as a *nullable* boolean, and the two never coordinate to check that they agree.

So it's not that dynamic && and || work on nullables. It's just that they happen to be implemented in a way that is a little bit too lenient, compared with the static case. This should probably be considered a bug, but we will never fix it, since that would be a breaking change. Also it would hardly help anyone to tighten the behavior.

Hopefully this explains what happens and why! This is an intriguing area, and I often find myself baffled by the consequences of the decisions we made when we implemented dynamic. This question was delicious - thanks for bringing it up!

Mads

Comment: I can see that these short-circuiting operators are special, since with dynamic binding we are not really allowed to know the type of the second operand in the case where we short-circuit. Maybe the spec should mention that? Of course, since everything inside a `dynamic` is boxed, we cannot tell the difference between a `bool?` which `HasValue`, and a "simple" `bool`.

Answer (score 6):

> Is this correct behavior?

Yes, I'm pretty sure it is.

> How can you infer that from the spec?

Section 7.12 of C# Specification Version 5.0, has information regarding the conditional operators `&&` and `||` and how dynamic binding relates to them. The relevant section:

> If an operand of a conditional logical operator has the compile-time type dynamic, then the expression is dynamically bound (§7.2.2). In this case the compile-time type of the expression is dynamic, and the **resolution described below will take place at run-time using the run-time type of those operands** that have the compile-time type dynamic.

This is the key point that answers your question, I think. What is the resolution that happens at run-time? Section 7.12.2, User-Defined conditional logical operators explains:

> - The operation x && y is evaluated as T.false(x) ? x : T.&(x, y), where T.false(x) is an invocation of the operator false declared in T, and T.&(x, y) is an invocation of the selected operator &
> - The operation x || y is evaluated as T.true(x) ? x : T.|(x, y), where T.true(x) is an invocation of the operator true declared in T, and T.|(x, y) is an invocation of the selected operator |.

In both cases, the first operand x will be converted to a bool using the `false` or `true` operators. Then the appropriate logical operator is called. With this in mind, we have enough information to answer the rest of your questions.

> But the evaluation for xx of A || B lead to no binding-time exception, and only the property A was read, not B. Why does this happen?

For the `||` operator, we know it follows `true(A) ? A : |(A, B)`. We short circuit, so we won't get a binding time exception. Even if `A` was `false`, we would *still* not get a runtime binding exception, because of the specified resolution steps. If `A` is `false`, we then do the `|` operator, which can successfully handle null values, per Section 7.11.4.

> Evaluating A && B (for yy) also leads to no binding-time error. And here both properties are retrieved, of course. Why is this allowed by the run-time binder? If the returned object from B is changed to a "bad" object (like a string), a binding exception does occur.

For similar reasons, this one also works. `&&` is evaluated as `false(x) ? x : &(x, y)`. `A` can be successfully converted to a `bool`, so there is no issue there. Because `B` is null, the `&` operator is lifted (Section 7.3.7) from the one that takes a `bool` to one that takes the `bool?` parameters, and thus there is no runtime exception.

For both conditional operators, if `B` is anything other than a bool (or a null dynamic), runtime binding fails because it can't find an overload that takes a bool and a non-bool as parameters. However, this only happens if `A` fails to satisfy the first conditional for the operator (`true` for `||`, `false` for `&&`). The reason this happens is because dynamic binding is quite lazy. It won't try to bind the logical operator unless `A` is false and it has to go down that path to evaluate the logical operator. Once `A` fails to satisfy the first condition for the operator, it will fail with the binding exception.

> If you try B as first operand, both B || A and B && A give runtime binder exception.

Hopefully, by now, you already know why this happens (or I did a bad job explaining). The first step in resolving this conditional operator is to take the first operand, `B`, and use one of the bool conversion operators (`false(B)` or `true(B)`) before handling the logical operation. Of course, `B`, being `null` cannot be converted to either `true` or `false`, and so the runtime binding exception happens.

Comment: No surprise that with `dynamic` the binding happens at run-time using the actual types of the instances, not the compile-time types (your first quote). Your second quote is irrelevant since no type here overloads the `operator true` and `operator false`. An `explicit operator` returning `bool` is something else than `operator true` and `false`. It is hard to read the spec in any way that allows `A && B` (in my example), without also allowing `a && b` where the `a` and `b` are statically typed nullable booleans, i.e. `bool? a` and `bool? b`, with binding at compile-time. Yet that is disallowed.

Answer (score -1):

The Nullable type does not define Conditional logical operators || and &&.
I suggest you following code:

```
bool a = true;
bool? b = null;

bool? xxxxOR = (b.HasValue == true) ? (b.Value || a) : a;
bool? xxxxAND = (b.HasValue == true) ? (b.Value && a) : false;
```