# Do lifted operators on nullable value types employ short-circuiting?

Tags: c#, language-lawyer, short-circuiting, lifted-operators

I wonder whether code like this should execute `GetAnotherValue()`?

```
int? x1 = null;
var check = x1 <= GetAnotherValue();
```

I assume it shouldn't since that sounds more reasonable to me. But I'm not sure if this is guaranteed. As far as I can find, the [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#lifted-operators) doesn't say anything about this.

EDIT:

I found some more specification docs on the topic of [expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#lifted-operators). It still isn't clear though.

It seems like lifted operators convert both operands to nullable equivalents, then check for nulls and call the original operators if needed.

This would imply my `GetAnotherValue()` method would get executed, to produce the second `int?` value for the lifted comparison. Am I correct with this interpretation?

Comment: What happens if you put a breakpoint in `GetAnotherValue()`?

Comment: Have a look what the compiler does: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALAPgAgJgIwFgBQcDMACR2DC2A3utmbjnFNgLIAUAlMaeawJYB2ALgPzZhJsAXmwcArgBsJAbhasycJAE46A7AB4RANQCGEsQFNGDWWlYBfOfNZWs2Tl2y79RhlZJnruAOzYAIjpcBgAqbAC2BgB0AHIA9gDukQDKBgDGsRwAJqYW6OZAA===

Comment: It does execute the method. I'd say that's unfortunate. It means that we need to write ugly code like `x1.HasValue && x1.Value <= GetAnotherValue()` if we wish to be optimal.

Comment: I guess calling no matter what makes sense in a way. If both arguments were anything other than a nullable value type, it would also execute the method. Why should nullables be any different.

Comment: [Why are there no lifted short-circuiting operators on `bool?`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5204366/1364007)