# Why && and || cannot be used on boolean nullable type?

Tags: c#

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#nullable-boolean-logical-operators
It says

> The conditional logical operators && and || don't support bool? operands.

It looks like you can only use bitwise & and | on bool?
But why?

Comment: [Nullable<T>: and overloaded operators, bool? & bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303181/nullablet-and-overloaded-operators-bool-bool)

Comment: Well, what do you think the results should be, depending on the values? Why?